# Cannot find path "_____" because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script that can transfer a file for a specified folder. I keep getting this error :

```
 Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\' because it 
 does not exist.
 At line:6 char:14
 +     $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\Rover" - 
 Recurse |  ...
 +              
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 
 (\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\:String) [Get-ChildItem], 
 ItemNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
 PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Am I missing something?

the path is working if manually access it over the network. All files are on my personal NAS and I tried using IP then folder path still getting the same error.

I have been using this command:
`$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\Rover" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) }`

This is just a simple transferring file from NAS1 Storage Drive to another NAS2. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should it be \\personalcloud ?

Comment: sorry that one is edited one I copied the wrong one it should be $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\Rover" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) } but same erro result.

Comment: It looks like it cannot find \CCTV. Check spelling, spaces, etc etc. Even if you don't have a child item that meets this criteria, you would not get this error. There is an issue with the path in code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten a character in your UNC path.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\Rover" -Recurse | `
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) }
```

You will need to use the double slash to denote the path if it is a network path, such as your NAS.

Comment: sorry that one is edited one I copied the wrong one it should be $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\personalcloud\elmert\CCTV\Rover" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) } but same error result.

Comment: I posted the correct one I don't why above info is in a single slash. :(